# how to set first node as default selected value in WebDataTree

Tags: infragistics

I am using WebDataTree to display menu like below:

```
+First Node

       +first childNode

+Second Node

        +Second childNode

+Third Node  

        +Third childNode
```

From the above webdataTree menu, how can I set "+ First Node" as selected (default selected) when the page loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by the below code:

```
protected void WebDataTree1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    foreach (var item in WebDataTree1.AllNodes)
    {
        DataTreeNode treeNode = (DataTreeNode)item;
        if (treeNode.Text.Equals("Chocolate")) {
            treeNode.Selected = true;
            WebDataTree1.SelectedNodes.Add(treeNode);              
        }
    }
}
```